# Chain a request in retrofit using rxJava2 and populate the result in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to consume an API from thesportsdb to display lastmatch from specific league. in my recyclerview I want to show the team badge for every teams but when I request the lastmatch API it didn't include the team badge, only the id for each team and if I want to show the badge it require me to request the team profile which includes the url for the team badge.

Since I am new to rxJava so I am still familiarize myself with it. some posts suggest using flatmap but it kind a difficult for beginner like me to implement it.

this is the retrofitService:

```
interface FootballRest {

@GET("eventspastleague.php")
fun getLastmatch(@Query("id") id:String) : Flowable<FootballMatch>

@GET("lookupteam.php")
fun getTeam(@Query("id") id:String) : Flowable<Teams>
}
```

I used repository pattern

```
class MatchRepositoryImpl(private val footballRest: FootballRest) : MatchRepository {
override fun getFootballMatch(id: String): Flowable<FootballMatch> = footballRest.getLastmatch(id)

override fun getTeams(id: String): Flowable<Teams> = 
footballRest.getTeam(id)
}
```

and this is the presenter who make the call and send the data to the view:

```
class MainPresenter(val mView : MainContract.View, val matchRepositoryImpl: MatchRepositoryImpl) : MainContract.Presenter{

val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

val requestMatch = matchRepositoryImpl.getFootballMatch("4328")
val requestTeam = matchRepositoryImpl.getTeams()

override fun getFootballMatchData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(matchRepositoryImpl.getFootballMatch("4328")
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe{
                mView.displayFootballMatch(it.events)
            })
}
```

so far I only show the last match result, but I want also to show the badge team on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `map` operator combined with `lastElement().blockingGet()` for the second `Observable` for this and then return a `Pair` of results. A simple example could be as follows:

```
@Test
public fun test1() {
    Observable.just(1)
            .map {
                // here 'it' variable is calculated already so it can be passed to the second observable
                val result = Observable.just(2).lastElement().blockingGet()
                 Pair<Int, Int>(it, result)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { t -> System.out.println("First : " + t?.first + ", second : " + t?.second) }

    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

**Output**

> 1 2

If your second `Observable` depends on the result of the first one then just use the `it` variable inside the `map` operator and pass it to whatever place it's needed. So, if using the previous example your code could be converted to this:

```
override fun getFootballMatchData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(matchRepositoryImpl.getFootballMatch("4328").toObservable( 
            .map {
                // here 'it' variable is calculated already so it can be passed to the second observable
                val next = matchRepositoryImpl.getTeams(it).toObservable().lastElement().blockingGet()
                Pair<Int, Int>(it, next)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{ t ->
                mView.displayFootballMatch(t.first)
                mView.displayBadgeTeam(t.second)
            })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in order to call the getTeam function I need to pass an id parameter which should be emited from the getFootballMatch function

Comment: thanks, I haven't tried your answer, I will update the answer soon I've tried it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a blockingGet operator its probably easier for you to use a flatmap and return all of this data as a single stream.

You could achieve this by combining the *flatmap* and *zip* operator. This would look something like the following, where MatchData holds both the FootballMatch data along with the homeTeam and awayTeam data.

```
data class MatchData(val footballMatch: FootballMatch, val homeTeam: Teams, val awayTeam: Teams)
```

Your flatmap operation would then need to invoke the getTeams method for both home and away team which can then be combined with the footballMatch data through the zip oprator.

```
override fun getFootballMatchData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(matchRepositoryImpl.getFootballMatch("4328")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap { footballMatch ->
                Flowable.zip(
                        matchRepositoryImpl.getTeams(footballMatch.idHomeTeam),
                        matchRepositoryImpl.getTeams(footballMatch.idAwayTeam),
                        BiFunction { homeTeam: Teams, awayTeam: Teams ->
                            MatchData(
                                    footballMatch = footballMatch,
                                    homeTeam = homeTeam,
                                    awayTeam = awayTeam)
                        }
                )
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                mView.displayFootballMatch(it)
            })
}
```